# tensorflow tutorial code fails with AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Just installed tensorflow-gpu 1.10 on Win10 using Python 3.6.6 and CUDA 9.0
Trying the sample code at https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/notebooks/custom_training.ipynb#scrollTo=_WRu7Pze7wk8

Problems right at the top:

```
class Model(object):   def __init__(self):
    # Initialize variable to (5.0, 0.0)
    # In practice, these should be initialized to random values.
    self.W = tf.Variable(5.0)
    self.b = tf.Variable(0.0)
       def __call__(self, x):
    return self.W * x + self.b    model = Model()

assert model(3.0).numpy() == 15.0
```

When run on Google Notebook it fails with

> RuntimeError: tf.Variable not supported when eager execution is enabled. Please use tf.contrib.eager.Variable instead

You should fix that.  With it fixed, the code runs without error on Notebook.

However when I copy it to a local .py file and run that, I get this really unexpected error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "linear.py", line 15, in 
>       assert model(3.0).numpy() == 15.0
>   AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

However in Python's interactive mode...

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> v = tf.contrib.eager.Variable(4.7)
>>> print( v.numpy() )
4.7
>>>
```

What gives??
(please bear in mind that I am a total Python and tensorflow noob)

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the `RuntimeError` in the Google Notebook. You're looking at the version of the notebook in the `master` branch in GitHub. That version of the notebook is meant to be in sync with the `master` branch of the codebase, where `tf.Variable` works just fine. If you're looking for the notebook corresponding to a particular release version of TensorFlow, you should look at the version in the corresponding release branch. For example, https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/notebooks/eager_basics.ipynb It seems www.tensorflow.org/tutorials is incorrectly linking to the master branch version, so that is certainly a bug on the website.

**Update**: The website has been fixed, links should point to the appropriate release branch.

2. The second error suggests that there is either a missing call to `tf.enable_eager_execution()` or the code is being run inside a `with tf.Graph().as_default()` block. Is that what might be happening?

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am getting the same error as OP. Just checked the TF version on both my colab notebook and the official colab notebook - they are the same. This is really puzzling.